# pyspark - how to maintain schema after dataFrame.randomSplit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a large s3 json semi-structured file that creates 40K partitions. 
The code is simple however, when I end up writing a result set of a query, it also creates almost 40K files, mostly 0kb.

So to resolve the issue, I thought of creating a new dataframe of the result set, which solves the problem since from 40K partitions, I now have less than a hundred.

```
reduced_partition_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(original_df.collect(), original_df.schema)
```

However, there are few result_set that returns a really larger number of files, causing the collector to run out of memory. So I thought I will split the dataframe if it reaches a certain record count threshold.

```
split_dataframe_array = original_df.randomSplit(split_weights)
```

However, when I did a split, at certain points, the schema that a split creates is now different than the original.

Is there a way to retain the schema or prevent df frame re-inferring the schema after splits?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the key goal is to reduce the number of partitions, perhaps you can run .coalesce(100) so your DataFrame of 40K partitions could be reduced down to 100 partitions?    As for the schema changing, this implies that you have different schema for different JSON files (e.g. some files have various attributes while other files do not).  If you use coalesce or repartition based on the original DataFrame schema you should be able to keep it.

Comment: @DennyLee -- thanks for the response, I did try coalesce(40000/10) or reparation (which I thought would still not be enough reduction), but it caused "contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB", then the job just stalled. That's why I am looking into split.

Comment: Got it - could you perhaps `.repartition` using a specific key that allows you to shuffle and distribute the data more evenly among the workers?  The quick concern I had was with a `.collect` it pushes everything to the driver and then pushes everything back out to the worker nodes.  If you can .repartition by some attribute that forces a distributed shuffle, you may be able to avoid the task too large issue.